# Porting WPF XAML code to Silverlight XAML code

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have some WPF XAML code that I am having some major issues with when trying to make a Silverlight equivalent. Now before anyone starts ranting about how the two aren't cross compatible, I already know that. I need to create a Silverlight application with a similar look and feel to the code I have now. I was able to get all of my C# classes converted but the XAML code is being a pain. Here is the WPF's XAML code that I'm having issues with:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
    <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" Cursor="SizeAll"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The issue is that I can't see MoveThumb under s:, which is the namespace of my project (MoveThumb is a C# class). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is all of the code for the Silverlight project. Do realize that I am nowhere near done with this transition, and I'm not necessarily asking for help on other issues with other parts of the code; just this one portion (the part under Designer Item Template.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightFlowConnectors.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:SilverlightFlowConnectors"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- MoveThumb Template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MoveThumbTemplate" TargetType="s:MoveThumb">
        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- Designer Item Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}">

        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Canvas>
    <ContentControl Width="130"
                MinWidth="50"
                Height="130"
                MinHeight="50"
                Canvas.Top="150"
                Canvas.Left="470">
        <Ellipse Fill="Red"
           IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Width="130"
                MinWidth="50"
                Height="130"
                MinHeight="50"
                Canvas.Top="150"
                Canvas.Left="150">
        <Path Fill="Blue"
        Data="M 0,5 5,0 10,5 5,10 Z"
        Stretch="Fill"
        IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Width="130"
        MinWidth="50"
        Height="130"
        MinHeight="50"
        Canvas.Top="150"
        Canvas.Left="150"
        Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
        <Path Fill="Blue"
            Data="M 0,5 5,0 10,5 5,10 Z"
            Stretch="Fill"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: There's no SizeAll cursor in SL, and hard to say for the rest without knowing how you have your namespace's set up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create specify a namespace short string `s` which targets where you have MoveThumb currently, or fix the listing you ported over. Just redo `s` with intellisense's help if nothing else.

Comment: I already did do that (I didn't feel the need to include code that wasn't completely necessary). The intellisense will pick up my class outside of the Control Template, but not inside of it.

Comment: @user3311309 Does `s` contain any other items which you can access in xaml? That might give you a clue why `s` is not working.

Comment: Outside of the ControlTemplate, I can access all my classes. Just inside of the ControlTemplate, I can only access the MainPage. Inside the Grid, I can't access anything. This really has me stumped. I feel like I'm missing something here.